# Integral on $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I begin with measure and integral theory. I want to give answer on the following statement:

*Suppose $l^{\infty}$ is the Rieszspace of all bounded functions on $\mathbb{N}$. Define  $\phi\colon\ell^{\infty}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by: $$\phi(f)=2^{-1}f(1)+2^{-2}f(2)+\cdots.$$ Prove that $\phi$ defines an integral on $l^{\infty}$.*

I did it on the following way: That $\phi$ is positiv is clear. Now suppose the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $0$ with all $f_n$ positive. Thus the following holds:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall\epsilon>0\ \exists N>0\ \forall n>N: f_n(x)<\epsilon$$
But then we have:

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty{\frac{f_n(x)}{2^x}}<\epsilon\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^x}}$$

This proves that $(\phi(f_n))$ also tends to zero, true?! Thus $\phi$ defines an integral.

---

Is this proof good?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Your definition of "integral" is "positive (continuous) linear functional"?

Comment: Yes, and i am sorry the norm have to be the sup norm not the 1-norm -.-

Answer (score 2):

As you say, $\phi$ is obviously positive. For continuity, you need for there to exists $M>0$ such that
$$
|\phi(f)| < M \quad \forall f \in \ell^{\infty} \text{ such that } \|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1
$$
Take
$$
M = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
Then, for any $f\in \ell^{\infty}$ such that $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1$, it follows that
$$
|f(j)| \leq 1 \quad \forall j\in \mathbb{N}
$$
Now just use the inequality you have up there.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do we have the same definitions? Suppose $F$ is a Rieszspace and define $F^+$ to be the space $$F^+:=\{f\in F: f(x)\in[0,\infty)\ \forall x\}$$ We say $\phi$ is an integral if the following holds: $f_1,f_2,\ldots\in F^+$, $f_n$ pointwise to zero then $\phi(f)\rightarrow 0$ Is this the same?

Comment: If $f$ is an element of a Riesz space, what do you mean by $f(1), f(2)$, etc.?